# Swift onclick textfield image

Tags: swift

I have got a textfield in my Swift code

```
let PassINP: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()

    textField.rightViewMode = .always
    var imageR = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:7,y:4,width:24,height:27))
    imageR.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "eye")
    var paddingR = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:40, height: 32))
    paddingR.addSubview(imageR)
    textField.rightView = paddingR

    textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    return textField
}()
```

And i want to call a function when `rightView` is clicked.How can i achieve that?
I have tried adding this code

```
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.rightViewTapped))
    paddingR.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

But it was not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to add `TapGesture` to `rightView` of your `UITextField`.

```
//Add UITapGestureRecognizer to your PassINP's rightView `viewDidLoad`
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(favoriteButtonPressed))
PassINP.rightView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Now add `rightViewTapped` method to handle the tap on the `rightView`

```
func rightViewTapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("rightViewTapped")
}
```

Comment: should i put that function outside of `PassINP` or inside? I put it outside and it is not working

Comment: @Centill Obviously outside the `PassINP` block with your other function that you have added with your class.

Comment: @Centill Have you try adding action, is it working now?

Comment: Action was added from beggining and unfortunately it is still not working

Comment: @Centill Edit your question with what you are trying and what is not working, is it not printing `rightViewTapped` in the console?

Comment: No it is not printing anything

Comment: @Centill Ok, Edit your question with what you have tried.

Comment: @Centill That's why i'm asking you to add the code where you are using this code that will give idea why it is not working.

Comment: @Centill You need to add these  `let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.rightViewTapped))
    paddingR.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)` line inside your `PassINP` block and have you added that function.

Comment: That's exactly how i did that

Comment: Is this code inside some `ViewController` have you added that PassINP field in your screen?

Comment: `PassINP` is inside `ViewController` class and i have added it as a subview inside `viewdidload`

Comment: @Centill Check the edited answer and remove the tapGesture from the ` `PassINP` block and add it inside the `viewDidLoad` like the current edited answer will works for you.

Comment: Now we talking:)Thanks for thy help!

Comment: @Centill Welcome mate :)